# Shader - Object depth from camera in linear scale from 0 to 1

Tags: unity-game-engine, opengl, three.js, glsl, shader

I am trying to write a shader that computes the depth of a mesh from a camera with a linear scale from 0 to 1.

A vertex that is the closest to the camera would have a value of 0, whereas the vertex that is the farthest from the camera would have a value of 1. Also, if the camera is rotated, the depth values of the mesh must adapt to the change.

Here is an image to support the understanding.

[image: Image Link]

From the image, you can see that the closest vertices alpha is set to 0 as compared to the value of 1 for the farthest vertices.

I would like to achieve this effect, even when the camera is rotated.

From this [Shader - Calculate depth relative to Object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26328666/shader-calculate-depth-relative-to-object), I can find the closest vertex, but I am finding it difficult to calculate the farthest point of the mesh from the camera.

The bounding box of the mesh could be used, but if I rotate the camera, I need to recompute the bounding box. Hence, I would like to know if there is any solution that could be used using the matrices available?

**PS:** I am trying to implement this effect in both three.js and Unity.

Comment: see [How to correctly linearize depth in OpenGL ES in iOS?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42515399/2521214)

Answer (score 0):

At least in `three.js` there is an official demo that produces your intended effect (just with inverted colors meaning white nearest): https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_depth_texture

The idea is to render the depth to a texture and then use this information in a custom shader. The relevant code in the fragment shader is:

```
float readDepth( sampler2D depthSampler, vec2 coord ) {
    float fragCoordZ = texture2D( depthSampler, coord ).x;
    float viewZ = perspectiveDepthToViewZ( fragCoordZ, cameraNear, cameraFar );
    return viewZToOrthographicDepth( viewZ, cameraNear, cameraFar );
}

void main() {
    // readDepth() will return a linearized depth value that will be used to compute the fragment's color value
    float depth = readDepth( tDepth, vUv );

    gl_FragColor.rgb = 1.0 - vec3( depth ); // change this bit to invert colors
    gl_FragColor.a = 1.0;
}
```

`perspectiveDepthToViewZ()` and `viewZToOrthographicDepth()` are helper functions defined in the `packing` shader chunk which is included right at the top of the shader's source code.

`three.js R116`