# Three.js: Increase point size as camera gets closer to point

Tags: javascript, three.js, glsl

I am working on a scene ([easier to see on bl.ocks.org than below](https://bl.ocks.org/duhaime/abffb58a2ef2886ff12038c3abef4439)) in Three.js that would benefit greatly from using points as the rendering primitive, as there are ~200,000 quads to represent, and representing those quads with points would take 4 times fewer vertices, which means fewer draw calls and higher FPS.

Now I'm trying to make the points larger as the camera gets closer to a given point. If you zoom straight in within the scene below, you should see this works fine. But if you drag the camera to the left or right, the points gradually grow smaller, despite the fact that the camera's proximity to the points seems constant. My intuition says the problem must be in the vertex shader, which sets `gl_PointSize`:

```js
(function() {

  /**
  * Generate a scene object with a background color
  **/

  function getScene() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    scene.background = new THREE.Color(0xaaaaaa);
    return scene;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the camera to be used in the scene. Camera args:
  *   [0] field of view: identifies the portion of the scene
  *     visible at any time (in degrees)
  *   [1] aspect ratio: identifies the aspect ratio of the
  *     scene in width/height
  *   [2] near clipping plane: objects closer than the near
  *     clipping plane are culled from the scene
  *   [3] far clipping plane: objects farther than the far
  *     clipping plane are culled from the scene
  **/

  function getCamera() {
    var aspectRatio = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(75, aspectRatio, 0.1, 10000);
    camera.position.set(0, 1, -6000);
    return camera;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the renderer to be used in the scene
  **/

  function getRenderer() {
    // Create the canvas with a renderer
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias: true});
    // Add support for retina displays
    renderer.setPixelRatio(window.devicePixelRatio);
    // Specify the size of the canvas
    renderer.setSize(window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight);
    // Add the canvas to the DOM
    document.body.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    return renderer;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the controls to be used in the scene
  * @param {obj} camera: the three.js camera for the scene
  * @param {obj} renderer: the three.js renderer for the scene
  **/

  function getControls(camera, renderer) {
    var controls = new THREE.TrackballControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
    controls.zoomSpeed = 0.4;
    controls.panSpeed = 0.4;
    return controls;
  }

  /**
  * Generate the points for the scene
  * @param {obj} scene: the current scene object
  **/

  function addPoints(scene) {
    // this geometry builds a blueprint and many copies of the blueprint
    var geometry  = new THREE.InstancedBufferGeometry();

    geometry.addAttribute( 'position',
      new THREE.BufferAttribute( new Float32Array( [0, 0, 0] ), 3));

    // add data for each observation
    var n = 10000; // number of observations
    var translation = new Float32Array( n * 3 );
    var translationIterator = 0;

    for (var i=0; i<n*3; i++) {
      switch (translationIterator % 3) {
        case 0:
          translation[translationIterator++] = ((i * 50) % 10000) - 5000;
          break;
        case 1:
          translation[translationIterator++] = Math.floor((i / 160) * 50) - 5000;
          break;
        case 2:
          translation[translationIterator++] = 10;
          break;
      }
    }

    geometry.addAttribute( 'translation',
      new THREE.InstancedBufferAttribute( translation, 3, 1 ) );

    var material = new THREE.RawShaderMaterial({
      vertexShader: document.getElementById('vertex-shader').textContent,
      fragmentShader: document.getElementById('fragment-shader').textContent,
    });
    var mesh = new THREE.Points(geometry, material);
    mesh.frustumCulled = false; // prevent the mesh from being clipped on drag
    scene.add(mesh);
  }

  /**
  * Render!
  **/

  function render() {
    requestAnimationFrame(render);
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
    controls.update();
  };

  /**
  * Main
  **/

  var scene = getScene();
  var camera = getCamera();
  var renderer = getRenderer();
  var controls = getControls(camera, renderer);
  addPoints(scene);
  render();

})()
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <style>
  body { margin: 0; }
  canvas { width: 100vw; height: 100vw; display: block; }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/three.js/88/three.min.js'></script>
  <script src='https://rawgit.com/YaleDHLab/pix-plot/master/assets/js/trackball-controls.js'></script>

    <script type='x-shader/x-vertex' id='vertex-shader'>
    /**
    * The vertex shader's main() function must define `gl_Position`,
    * which describes the position of each vertex in screen coordinates.
    *
    * To do so, we can use the following variables defined by Three.js:
    *   attribute vec3 position - stores each vertex's position in world space
    *   attribute vec2 uv - sets each vertex's the texture coordinates
    *   uniform mat4 projectionMatrix - maps camera space into screen space
    *   uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix - combines:
    *     model matrix: maps a point's local coordinate space into world space
    *     view matrix: maps world space into camera space
    *
    * `attributes` can vary from vertex to vertex and are defined as arrays
    *   with length equal to the number of vertices. Each index in the array
    *   is an attribute for the corresponding vertex. Each attribute must
    *   contain n_vertices * n_components, where n_components is the length
    *   of the given datatype (e.g. for a vec2, n_components = 2; for a float,
    *   n_components = 1)
    * `uniforms` are constant across all vertices
    * `varyings` are values passed from the vertex to the fragment shader
    *
    * For the full list of uniforms defined by three, see:
    *   https://threejs.org/docs/#api/renderers/webgl/WebGLProgram
    **/

    // set float precision
    precision mediump float;

    // specify geometry uniforms
    uniform mat4 modelViewMatrix;
    uniform mat4 projectionMatrix;

    // to get the camera attributes:
    uniform vec3 cameraPosition;

    // blueprint attributes
    attribute vec3 position; // sets the blueprint's vertex positions

    // instance attributes
    attribute vec3 translation; // x y translation offsets for an instance

    void main() {
      // set point position
      vec3 pos = position + translation;
      vec4 projected = projectionMatrix * modelViewMatrix * vec4(pos, 1.0);
      gl_Position = projected;

      // use the delta between the point position and camera position to size point
      float xDelta = pow(projected[0] - cameraPosition[0], 2.0);
      float yDelta = pow(projected[1] - cameraPosition[1], 2.0);
      float zDelta = pow(projected[2] - cameraPosition[2], 2.0);
      float delta  = pow(xDelta + yDelta + zDelta, 0.5);
      gl_PointSize = 20000.0 / delta;
    }
    </script>

    <script type='x-shader/x-fragment' id='fragment-shader'>
    /**
    * The fragment shader's main() function must define `gl_FragColor`,
    * which describes the pixel color of each pixel on the screen.
    *
    * To do so, we can use uniforms passed into the shader and varyings
    * passed from the vertex shader.
    *
    * Attempting to read a varying not generated by the vertex shader will
    * throw a warning but won't prevent shader compiling.
    **/

    precision highp float;

    void main() {
      gl_FragColor = vec4(1.0, 0.0, 0.0, 1.0);
    }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Does anyone see what I'm missing? Any help others can offer would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: @NicolBolas just so I know for the future, what kinds of questions are the opengl tags meant for? Should questions with those tags address specific opengl function calls?

Comment: It should be used for desktop OpenGL questions. You are using Three.js, which itself is using WebGL. And WebGL is a derivative of OpenGL ES, which is a derivative of desktop OpenGL. Tagging is all about finding people who are best capable of answering your question. And if your problem had something to do with WebGL or OpenGL ES, a user of desktop OpenGL who isn't familiar with the changes the other APIs made could easily give you a useless answer. Or worse, the *wrong* answer.

Comment: Sounds good! Is it safe to use the OpenGL ES 2.0 tag for WebGL questions?

Comment: Since you're not *directly* using OpenGL ES, I would say that [tag:three.js] is sufficient.

Comment: Sounds good more characters

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is due to the distortion caused by *rectilinear projection*, which takes the depth value of each point (the "proximity distance" you were referring to) to be its Z (or Y) coordinate in camera space; you are instead taking this to be the Euclidean distance from the camera's position.

[image]

The diagram illustrates that, as you move the camera's axis away from the point, the distance `delta` increases (the point shrinks) while the depth value (the "apparent proximity") stays constant. To fix this, just replace `delta` with the depth value `project[2]` (or `[1]` - I forgot which one OpenGL uses).

Note that if your `modelViewMatrix` is set up correctly according to convention, you shouldn't subtract by `cameraPosition`.

Comment: are you suggesting that I should size the points by delta(camera.z, vertex.z)? When I tried that, I found if one rotates the camera such that the camera's z value approaches the z plane on which all points are located, all points will grow equally large, despite the fact that many points are quite far from the camera in the x and y dimensions. I'm trying to make each point's size proportional to its proximity to the camera, which is why I'm using Euclidean distance. Clearly I'm missing something though. Does any of this make sense?

Comment: You are still confusing between Euclidean and the "rectilinear" distance I think. Again, you shouldn't subtract the camera's position once you project the vertex with the modelview matrix. If you insist on using the Euclidean distance (nothing wrong with that - it's basically how fisheye lenses work), the phenomenon you saw is as expected.

Comment: Ah, I think I see the discrepancy now. I'm working with the projected position, not the raw position I passed in to my attribute buffer. That makes sense. Do you know how I can avoid the fisheye effect? I'd like to make points behave a bit like quads do naturally (insofar as they get bigger as you get closer)

Comment: I can't believe I did that. I'll accept this! If you have notions on how to avoid the fisheye effect, I'd certainly be grateful for any ideas you can offer

Comment: For others who end up here, just change `pow(projected[0] - cameraPosition[0], 2.0);` to `pow(pos[0] - cameraPosition[0], 2.0);` for the x, y, and z dimensions

Comment: Well, the fisheye effect comes from exactly what you did originally, i.e. using the Euclidean distance as the proximity. So just use the 0-coordinate instead.

Comment: if you have a second, would you maybe be able to send a link to how one can "use the 0-coordinate" to avoid the fisheye effect? I'm returning to this problem after some time. Any links or edits to your post you can offer would be hugely helpful!

Comment: I meant change `gl_PointSize = 20000.0 / delta;` to `gl_PointSize = 20000.0 / pos[0]`, i.e. as I explained above use only the screen-space depth coordinate. I think the correct index should be 1 or 2 though - I'm just paraphrasing your "*For others who end up here*" comment. **EDIT** - according to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16131963/depth-as-distance-to-camera-plane-in-glsl) it is the Z-coordinate, i.e. `pos[2]`.